# How can I add a context menu option for my macOS swift app?

Tags: swift, macos, menu

I'm creating an app (in swift) similar to dropbox and I want to create an option "Add file to app name" and add it to the right click menu. On click I'd like to have the app open up and have the file loaded for the user to decide where it is saved. I have looked on the web extensively and can't find any other sources for help. Only looking for help on adding the menu option.

Comment: Are you talking about the Finder?

Comment: @ssswift Nope, I'm talking about the menu that will pop up if you right click on something in a browser.